# Consulta laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Hola estoy haciendo lo intentado hacer algo medio complejo que no me sale, es lo siguiente:
Tengo 3 tablas:

- users: la tabla que viene por default en laravel
- tipo_pagos : Muestro los tipos de pagos
- pago_users : obtengo el id de tipo_pagos y el id de users

consultas que hago para saber cual esta seleccionado:

```
 public function index($id)
{
    $pago = DB::table('tipo_pagos')->get();

    $paus = DB::table('pago_users as pu')
        ->where('pu.idvendedor', $id)
        ->join('tipo_pagos as tp', 'pu.idtipo_pago', '=', 'tp.idtipo_pago')
        ->get();
    return view('reserva.tipo-pago', compact('pago','paus', 'id'));
}
```

bueno ahora quiero mostrar los tipos de pagos seleccionados en la vista "reserva.tipo-pago" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div class="container">
    <h2>Tipos de Pagos</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Selecionar tipo de pago</h4>
        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'tipo.pago.update', 'id'=>'form' ,'method'=>'POST','autocomplete' => 'off')) !!}
        {{Form::token()}}
            @foreach($pago as $pa)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="{{$pa->idtipo_pago}}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$pa->nombre}}</label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$id}}" name="iduser">
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Pagos seleccionados</h4>
        @foreach($paus as $pa)
            <div class="form-check">
                <input checked type="checkbox" disabled class="form-check-input" value="{{$pa->idtipo_pago}}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$pa->nombre}}</label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <br>
        <button form="form" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Aplicar</button>
        <button form="form" class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Calcelar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

bien ahora me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para marcar los inputs del lado izquierdo, osea los que estén seleccionados que se marquen, para poder desaserme de la columna del lado derecho

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera, no lo tengo probado pero creo que deberia funcionarte:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Tipos de Pagos</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Selecionar tipo de pago</h4>
        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'tipo.pago.update', 'id'=>'form' ,'method'=>'POST','autocomplete' => 'off')) !!}
        {{Form::token()}}
            @foreach($pago as $pa)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" {{ $paus->search(function($item, $key) use ($pa){ return $item->nombre == $pa->nombre; }) !== false ? "checked" : "" }} class="form-check-input" value="{{$pa->idtipo_pago}}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$pa->nombre}}</label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$id}}" name="iduser">
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <br>
        <button form="form" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Aplicar</button>
        <button form="form" class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Calcelar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sos un genio, muchas gracias!! ahora voy a ver la logica que usaste porque se ve muy buena